# What data should I use to track the player position on a world at the same size of the earth in a multiplayer game?

Tags: c++

I guess this kind of game or simulator already exist somewhere, but I'm not sure...

Let's imagine I'm making a game where the proportions of the planet earth and the humans beings on it are the same as in the reality. I can't only use longitude/latitude with float because when being far away from the origin, precision would be lost: when the float exponent gets too high, the digit at the right would be rounded and thus, not considered. Or to say it simpler, `float` are not precise enough to position an object on earth using longitude/latitude while keeping smooth movements.

Since there is a need to track each player's position in an homogenous way, I'm thinking about dividing the world map into indexed subparts (thus integers), and then precisely position the player using a float or double.

This would look like this:

```
struct position_on_earth
{
int sector_x, sector_y;
float pos_x; pos_y;
};
```

Is it potentially faster to use this kind of data instead of using `double`s ?

Comment: Take a look at the answers found here:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/in-what-kind-of-variable-type-is-the-player-position-stored-on-a-mmorpg-such-as-w

Comment: In fact, I asked this question.

Comment: Haha. Oops =D Didn't notice that ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Earth's Surface Area ~ 5.1×10^14 square meters

If the world were flat, you would have enough precision from making pos_x and pos_y 32bit integers to divide the entire world into a uniform sub-millimeter grid. Depending on the scale of your simulation, this might well be enough precision.

If you're going for a spherical world, however, you're going to need a different kind of coordinate system.

EDIT: In fact, just using a dumb 32bit int grid still isn't all that bad if you move to a sphere! Some more details about earth:

Mean radius 6,371.0 km
Equatorial radius 6,378.1 km
Polar radius 6,356.8 km

Lets say we put our model earth in a cube with sides 13,000 km in length. If we use 32bit ints for x, y and z coordinates, we still get sub-centimeter precision. As an added bonus, we don't need to handle altitude / depth as a separate special case anymore (although this might be viewed as a disadvantage, since we will need to check the direction to the planet's center when we apply gravity).

Comment: +1 Assuming the stats are correct, then it would seem that there is no precision problem.

Answer (score 1):

Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed

[ECEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)

Edit: don't worry about the gravity vector, it's always easy to get a unit vector to the origin.
Doubles will do your XYZ units just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my other answer to your other very similar [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/in-what-kind-of-variable-type-is-the-player-position-stored-on-a-mmorpg-such-as-w), you should read ["The Continuous World of Dungeon Siege"](http://scottbilas.com/files/2003/gdc_san_jose/continuous_world_paper.html). He does indeed suggest dividing the world up into a "relational node-based coordinate system, in which each chunk of geometry (Siege Node) has its own coordinate space". Your struct seems to mirror this, so I think you're doing fine.

Comment: The Dungeon Siege paper is good reading, but may be overkill. The grid-based system jokoon proposed is still an absolute coordinate space; Dungeon Siege had no absolute coordinates. This lets you do much cooler things, but is also a lot less straightforward to think about.

Comment: yes, but the implementation is a little more sophisticated. I like the kiss principle :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the author now recommends people take a different approach. See the notes at http://scottbilas.com/games/dungeon-siege/

Comment: What does he mean by "the 'giant bricks' model of world subdivision"? (if it's in the paper just say so, I haven't read it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is potentially faster as long as nothing which needs a position (this includes path finding or finding out the distance to places halfway across the planet) crosses the section boundaries all that often - in other words, if all your algorithms and procedures have a strong *locality* to them. If your use case is the other way around, I'd suggest storing the position in precise, global uint32 values (which would have about a centimetre precision) and storing a float (or even just float16 if your hardware supports it) *displacement* value from this position for display on screen, local physics simulation and similar cases.